# How to access all child attributes of type ActionForm defined within a Parent class Object

Tags: java, reflection

Please share your thoughts to resolve following problem statement.

Objective:
I am trying to develop an Utility in Java 1.6 using reflection. This Utility will access each attribute, non-nullable attribute(s) will be passed through a specific validation routine.

Problem Statement:
I am able to access attributes of class ParentBean, ClassB and ClassC. But I am unable to access attributes of ClassD, ClassE. My code goes here.

```
public class ParentBean extends ActionForm {
    private String fullName;
    private ClassB classB;
    private ClassC classC;
    // getters and setters
}

public class ClassB extends ActionForm {  
    private long classBid;
    private Collection hobby;
    private ClassD classD;
    private ClassE classE;
    // getters and setters
}

public class ClassC extends ActionForm {
    private long classCid;
    // getters and setters
}

public class ClassD extends ActionForm {
    private long classDid;
    private String addr1;
    // getters and setters
}

public class ClassE extends ActionForm {
    private long classEid;
    private String contactVal;
    private ClassF classF;
    // getters and setters
}

public class ClassF extends ActionForm {
    private long classFid;
    private String attribute;
    // getters and setters
}

public class Validate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ParentBean objParentBean = new ParentBean();
        objParentBean.setFullName("MALCOM ANDRWES");
        ClassB objClassB = new ClassB();
        Collection hobby = new ArrayList();
        hobby.add("CRICKET");
        objClassB.addHobby(hobby);
        ClassD objClassD = new ClassD();
        objClassD.setAddr1("123 MAIN STREET");
        objClassB.setClassD(objClassD);
        ClassE objClassE = new ClassE();
        objClassE.setContactVal("97862082202");
        ClassF objClassF = new ClassF();
        objClassF.setAttribute("XXX"); 
        objClassE.setClassF(objClassF);
        objClassB.setClassE(objClassE);
        // Call Validation Routine
        performValidation(actionFormObj);
    }

    private static void performValidation(ActionForm form) {
        Object formObj = form;
        List<Field> formFields = getAllFields(formObj.getClass());
        List<Field> childFormAttributeLst = validateForm(formObj, formFields);
        if (!childFormAttributeLst.isEmpty()) {
            validateChildForm(childFormAttributeLst, formObj, form);
        }
    }

    private static List<Field> validateForm(Object formObj,List<Field> formFields) {
        List<Field> childFormAttributeLst = new ArrayList<Field>();
        for (Field field : formFields) {
            if (isPrimitive(field.getType())) {
                validate(formObj, field);
            } else if (isCollection(field.getType())) {
                isCollectionNotNull(formObj, field);
            } else {
                childFormAttributeLst.add(field);
            }
        }
        return childFormAttributeLst;
    }

    private static void validateChildForm(List<Field> childFormAttributeLst,Object formObj, ActionForm form) {
        List<Field> childFormLst = new ArrayList<Field>();
        Method m = null;
        Object chldFormObj = null;
        for (Field field : childFormAttributeLst) {
            try {
                StringBuffer fieldName = getFieldName(field);
                m = formObj.getClass().getMethod(fieldName.toString(),
new Class<?>[] {});
                try {
                    chldFormObj = m.invoke(formObj, null);
                    List<Field> formFields = getAllFields(chldFormObj.getClass());
                    childFormLst = validateForm(chldFormObj, formFields);
                    // Accessing inner Form bean attributes defined
                    if(!childFormLst.isEmpty()){
                        for (Field field2 : childFormLst) {
                            try{
                                StringBuffer fieldName1 = getFieldName(field2);
                                m = field.getType().getMethod(fieldName1.toString(),
new Class<?>[] {});
                                try{
                                    String invokingClass = field.getType().getName();
                                    // Below line throws error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
                                    Object formObj2 = m.invoke(formObj, null); 
                                } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
npe.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                npe.printStackTrace();
            }
        } // catch Blocks
    }
}

private static StringBuffer getFieldName(Field field) {
    StringBuffer fieldName = new StringBuffer("get"
+ field.getName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
+ field.getName().substring(1, field.getName().length()));
    return fieldName;
}

private static List<Field> getAllFields(Class<?> type) {
    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();
    for (Class<?> c = type; c != null; c = c.getSuperclass()) {
        if (!(Object.class == c || ActionForm.class == c)) {
            fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(c.getDeclaredFields()));
        }
    }
    return fields;
}

private static boolean isPrimitive(Class<?> typeClass) {
    if (typeClass == String.class
    || (typeClass == Integer.class || typeClass == Integer.TYPE)
    || typeClass == Timestamp.class
    || (typeClass == Boolean.class || typeClass == Boolean.TYPE)
    || (typeClass == Double.class || typeClass == double.class)
    || (typeClass == Long.class || typeClass == long.class)
    || (typeClass == Float.class || typeClass == float.class)
    || typeClass == java.util.Date.class
    || (typeClass == Character.class || typeClass == char.class)
    || (typeClass == Byte.class || typeClass == byte.class)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private static void validate(Object formObj, Field field) {
    try {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object obj = field.get(formObj);
        if (null != obj) {
            // Perform validation
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static boolean isCollection(Class<?> typeClass) {
    if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(typeClass)
    || Map.class.isAssignableFrom(typeClass)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private static void isCollectionNotNull(Object formObj, Field field) {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    try {
        if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
            validateCollection(formObj, field);
        } else if (Map.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
            validateMap(formObj, field);
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private static void validateMap(Object formObj, Field field) throws IllegalAccessException {
    Map map = (Map) field.get(formObj);
    if (!(null == map || map.isEmpty())) {
        Set setOfKeys = map.keySet();
        for (Object object : setOfKeys) {
            // perform validation
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private static void validateCollection(Object formObj, Field field) throws IllegalAccessException {
    Collection coll = (Collection) field.get(formObj);
    if (!(null == coll || coll.isEmpty())) {
        for (Object object : coll) {
            // perform validation
        }
    }
}

//superfluous closing brace?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    try {
                            StringBuffer fieldName1 = getFieldName(field2);
                            m = field.getType().getMethod(fieldName1.toString(),
                                    new Class <  ?  > []{});
                            //at this point m is overwritten
                            try {
                                String invokingClass = field.getType().getName();
                                // Below line throws error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
                                Object formObj2 = m.invoke(formObj, null);
                            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                                npe.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

There is a point in your code where you overwrite the method m, m becomes a method from the field inside the object formObj(chldFormObj), later on you get the error because you are trying to invoke a method from chldFormObj on the fromObj.

You should invoke the method on object chldFormObj.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your response. You are correct with your observation. 

My problem is how do I invoke the child object dynamically.

The invocation should be like below:
actionFormObj.getClassB().getClassD()

formObj refers to ParentBean object, but actually it should be object of ClassB

Comment: The best way is to do it recursively in method validateForm instead of adding child objects to a list, get the object, get its fields and call validateForm on it. You should however be extra careful because if you have circular references you can get an infinite loop.

Comment: Hi,
What I am trying to do is as follows:

1. Get attributes of ParentBean class.
2. Identify the primitive, Collection and other attributes of type form bean.
3. Store the child form bean attributes in a list.
3. Iterate over the child form bean list and repeat step 1-3.

Comment: Hi,
That sounds like a good suggestion. Really appreciate if I can get some code.  
Any suggestions on making the shared code work.

Comment: You can do that by calling validateForm on fromObj2 and by changing a few things: 1. don't create a new child list just add new elements to it.2 change this for (Field field : childFormAttributeLst) so you don't use for each anymore, that won't work once the list is changing.